# En ventana aparece como una sumatoria tanto de las horas, como de los minutos y segundos

Tags: tkinter, python-3.7

En ventana me aparece como una sumatoria tanto de las horas, como de los minutos y segundos, ¿alguno tiene idea de como solucionar este problema? La idea del proyecto es hacer un sistema con una cuenta regresiva para una determinada fecha que al llegar la misma, se cierre la ventana con un messagebox.

```
ventana = Tk()
ventana.title("Cuenta Regresiva")
ventana.resizable(0,0)
ventana.geometry("1000x750")
segundos = 1.555e+6

def countdown():
    global segundos
    if segundos > 0:
        segundos = segundos -1
        mins = segundos // 60
        horas = segundos // 3600
        dias = segundos // 86400
    
        m = str(mins)
        h = str(horas)
        d = str(dias)
    
        if dias < 100:
            h = '0' + str(dias)
        elif dias < 19:
            h = '00' + str(dias)
            se = segundos - (dias * 86400)
    
        if horas > 24:
            h = str(horas)
        elif horas <= 24:
            h = str(horas)
        elif horas < 432:
            h = '0' + str(horas)
            se = segundos - (horas * 3600)

        if mins > 59:
            m = str(mins)
        elif mins <= 59:
            m = str(mins)
        elif mins < 25920:
            m = '0' + str(mins)
        se = segundos - (mins * 60)
        s = str(se)

        if se < 10:
            s = '0' + str(se)
        
        time.set('  Restan  ' + d + ' dias ' + h + ' hs ' 
        + m + ' mins ' + s + ' segs')
        timer_Label.config(textvariable = time)
        ventana.after(1000, countdown)

    elif segundos == 0:
        messagebox.showinfo('Mensaje', 'Ya llego la hora, hay que irse !!! ')
        ventana.quit()
countdown()
```

Comment: ¿qué son `time, timer_Label`?

Comment: No me dejo poner el código completo, es la primera vez que estoy en este foro, sorry.


   frame3 = Frame(ventana, width=150, height=400)
   frame3.pack()

   time = StringVar()
   timer_Label = Label(ventana, font=('DS-Digital', 20))
   timer_Label.place(x=30, y=30)
   countdown()

Answer (score 0):

Al hacer `horas = segundos//86400` estás convirtiendo el **total** de segundos en horas. Imagino que sólo quieres convertir los segundos que corresponden al último día, pues los segundos anteriores ya estarían dentro de `dias`.

Es decir, si por ejemplo `segundos` empezara valiendo 93640 (que es 86400 + 3600*2 + 40), entonces querrías que se mostrara algo del estilo "1 dia, 2 horas, 40 segundos"). Pero al hacer `horas = 93640//3600` te va a salir 26, pues esos segundos son 26 horas. Y es que las primeras 24h ya estaban convertidas a días y por tanto hay que quitarlas.

La forma más típica de abordar este problema es la siguiente. Cuando conviertes a días el número total de segundos debes obtener por un lado un **cociente**, que es el número de días, y por otro un **resto**, que es el número de segundos que aún han sobrado y que son los que tendrías que convertir a horas.

Para obtener el cociente y el resto separadamente puedes hacerlo así:

```
dias = segundos // 86400
resto = segundos % 86400  # El operador % da el resto de la división
```

o si estás trabajando con un python moderno (3.7+) así:

```
dias, resto = divmod(segundos, 86400)
```

De cualquiera de las dos formas, el valor de `resto` es la nueva cantidad de segundos con la que debes continuar, para convertirlo en horas. Pero en esa conversión deberás usar la misma idea para encontrar el número de horas en el cociente y el número de segundos "sobrantes" en el resto (para convertirlo a minutos). En definitiva, harías algo así:

```
se = segundos
dias, se = divmod(se, 86400)
horas, se = divmod(se, 3600)
minutos, se = divmod(se, 60)
```

En lugar de usar una variable intermedia `resto` he usado `se`, que comienza valiendo el total de segundos pero va "menguando" para quedarse con los restos a medida que se va convirtiendo la cantidad a días, horas y minutos. El resto de la última división serán los segundos restantes, que quedan también en `se`.

## Extra

No uses un flotante para el número inicial de segundos. Mejor inicializalo como entero:

```
segundos = 1555000
```

No necesitas complicar tanto el código para anteponer ceros a ciertas cantidades, ni usar concatenaciones de cadenas o abusar de `str()`. Todo eso puedes hacerlo de forma muy simple utilizando f-strings y especificando dentro el formato. Por ejemplo:

```
mensaje = f'  Restan {dias} dias, {horas:02d} horas, {minutos:02d} minutos y {se:02d} segundos'
```

Esto producirá como resultado la siguiente cadena:

```
'  Restan 17 dias, 23 horas, 56 minutos y 40 segundos'
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar. Basicamente me hice terrible desorden al usar el operador de división entera.

Comment: @DaniLuna He editado la respuesta con un par de consejos adicionales. El segundo puede reducir tu código a una docena de líneas

Comment: buenisimo, ya hice las modificaciones, ahora me aparecio un problema. Cuando abro la ventana en la interfaz gráfica no se muestra que la cuenta regresiva esta en funcionamiento sino que esta congelada, tengo que hacerle otro tipo de modificación?

Comment: Sin ver tu código completo es imposible saber qué te falta. De todas formas, esa sería otra pregunta. Yo creo que por no alargarlo más podrías dejar esta así (de hecho la pregunta original está resuelta) y formular una nueva pregunta en el sitio con el código que tienes ahora mismo tras las modificaciones y el nuevo problema que aparece. Puedes leer [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) un rápido recorrido sobre cómo funciona el sitio, que no es un foro sino pregunta-respuesta.

Comment: Perfecto. No pasa nada entonces, muchas gracias.